# SQLalchemy core join and select without duplicate fields

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have two tables like that:

```py
class UserRole(tyrande.BaseModel):
  """SQLAlchemy UserRole model definition."""

  __tablename__ = 'user_role'

  id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, autoincrement=True, index=True, primary_key=True)
  type = sa.Column(sa.String, nullable=False, unique=True)


class User(tyrande.BaseModel):
  """SQLAlchemy User model definition."""

  __tablename__ = 'user'

  id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, autoincrement=True, index=True, primary_key=True)
  name = sa.Column(sa.String, index=True, nullable=False)
  email = sa.Column(sa.String, unique=True, index=True, nullable=False)
  password = sa.Column(sa.String, nullable=False)
  birth_date = sa.Column(sa.Date, nullable=False)
  role_id = sa.Column(
      sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey("user_role.id"), server_default='1')
  is_verified = sa.Column(
      sa.Boolean, server_default=sa.sql.expression.false(), nullable=False)
  create_date = sa.Column(
      sa.DateTime(timezone=True),
      server_default=sa.sql.func.now(), nullable=False)


users = User.__table__
user_roles = UserRole.__table__
```

and I want to make the following query:

```py
users.join(user_roles).select().where(users.c.email == 'dummy@dummy.com')
```

The execution of the query gives me the following result:

```py
<Record id=11 name='standard_user' email='dummy@dummy.com' password='$2b$12$gxeX1JQgTOQp45siGAwbhOYUQdi//YabPH.aG318ZTjwQs94/1k2K' birth_date=datetime.date(2020, 2, 23) role_id=1 is_verified=False create_date=datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 23, 15, 35, 8, 871941, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc) id=1 type='STANDARD'>
```

which has two fields called 'id', one from the `users` table and second from the `user_roles`. How can I get the one I want? It is very confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're joining `User` and `UserRole`:

```
users.join(user_roles)
```

that's why double `id` appears - both entities have `id`. If you run such a query (joining two tables with the same column name), the result would be the same.

The first id comes from the first table (`users`) and the second - from the second (`user_roles`).

I'm not sure, what you want to do, if you only want `User` entity, then run:

```
select([users]).select_from(users.join(user_roles).where(users.c.email == 'dummy@dummy.com'))
```

Or this to omit the second `id`:

```
select([users, user_roles.c.type]).select_from(users.join(user_roles).where(users.c.email == 'dummy@dummy.com'))
```

Comment: What if I want to get something like ```<Record id=11 name='standard_user'  ... role_id=1 role_type='STANDARD'>```?

Comment: @AlvaroGarcia no problem, use this select: `select([users, user_roles.c.type])`

Comment: I'm getting the following error ```sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: SQL expression object expected, got object of type <class 'list'> instead``` I'm using encode/databases project to make the query as following: ```data = await tyrande.db.fetch_one(query)```

Comment: @AlvaroGarcia use `tyrande.db.fetch_row`

Comment: I am still getting ```sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: SQL expression object expected, got object of type <class 'list'> instead``` this error when executting ```select([users, user_roles.c.type]```

Comment: @AlvaroGarcia I have updated the answer, I hope it'll work now